# In akka-http, do response entities need to be consumed in a sink when the response is anything other than 200?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

On this [akka-http documentation page](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.9/scala/http/client-side/request-level.html#Future-Based_Variant) there is a warning at the bottom:

> Be sure to consume the response entities
>   `dataBytes:Source[ByteString,Unit]` by for example connecting it to a
>   Sink (for example `response.entity.dataBytes.runWith(Sink.ignore)` if
>   you don't care about the response entity), since otherwise Akka HTTP
>   (and the underlying Streams infrastructure) will understand the lack
>   of entity consumption as a back-pressure signal and stop reading from
>   the underlying TCP connection!
>
> This is a feature of Akka HTTP that allows consuming entities (and
>   pulling them through the network) in a streaming fashion, and only on
>   demand when the client is ready to consume the bytes - it may be a bit
>   suprising at first though.

Why is this not needed in the case where the response's Status Code is not  `StatusCodes.OK`? Or is it in fact needed and the code example shown on that page (also below) missing that?

```
  def receive = {
    case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, headers, entity, _) =>
      log.info("Got response, body: " + entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString(""))(_ ++ _))
    case HttpResponse(code, _, _, _) =>
      //why not here?
      log.info("Request failed, response code: " + code)
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response entity should always be consumed however in practice the error responses are typically `HttpEntity.Strict` types and a failure to consume those won't cause any issues with back pressure.

For the interested, as of Akka 2.4.9 this behaviour is from [`SlotProcessor.running`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/62b4ecf67c042f05509c48ae9423978510062429/akka-http-core/src/main/scala/akka/http/impl/engine/client/PoolSlot.scala#L195) where it wraps the `HttpEntity` using [`HttpEntity.captureTermination`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/5d8dcc8ebc85e16524496e6fdca5c5298f04c788/akka-http-core/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpEntity.scala#L644).  This wrapping is used to signal that the response has been consumed and thus providing the right backpressure signals.  For a `HttpEntity.Strict` since the entity body is already in memory the `captureTermination` method will return a `Future.success(())` whereas the other types will wrap the `Source` and return a `Future` that completes when the underlying `Source` is completed.

Regarding the `HttpEntity` type returned, there aren't any guarantees, as far as the API is concerned, that certain responses will be `HttpEntity.Strict` which is why the recommendation is to always consume the response.  [HttpResponseParser](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/9dc474a10ac1887c9d280904974e91f4f9208299/akka-http-core/src/main/scala/akka/http/impl/engine/parsing/HttpResponseParser.scala#L171) is doing the work of parsing the responses.  As I understand when reading the response if the body is already read into memory (based on buffer size) and there is no transfer encoding then a `HttpEntity.Strict` can be returned as we've already done all the work.  Otherwise a `HttpEntity.Default` or `HttpEntity.Chunked` will be returned.

On last catch, if you use the `HttpEntity` as part of a server response (e.g. in a `complete` directive) then its possible for the server to timeout and not bother consuming the entity.  You can use the `withRequestTimeoutResponse` directive to consume response in this case.

Comment: thanks, do you have a reference to a place in the documentation or source code where you got this conclusion?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include links to the code.  Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for providing the deep dive. From the source code it still isnt clear to me how we can be confident that error responses are of type `HttpEntity.Strict` and therefore the entity body is all in memory (that is the centerpiece of it all, it would seem). There isn't a mention of Http responses in the [doc for HttpEntity](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.9/scala/http/common/http-model.html#HttpEntity). Given this, just to be safe, I'll consume the `response.entity` on all error responses